# MS server Error 3709. DESC: The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closedor invalid in this context

Tags: windows, installation, server, windows-installer

I am trying to install a program on a Windows machine and the error  get after linking the machine to the server registory is:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ROxl.png)

Please advise

Created registory on server and then tranferred the file to the machine that I want to install the program on.

This is the last process and I want both server and machine to be linked and the program to be successfully installed